# Regarding applying concept of analytic continuation in Analytic number theory

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory, analytic-continuation

I am studying analytic number theory from Tom M Apostol introduction to analytic number theory,

> Actually Concept of analytic continuation was not taught by my instructor who took complex analysis course. So I began self studying it for Complex Variables with Applications By Ponnusamy and Silvermann. 
>   But I doesn't feel confident in some theorems or exercises of Analytic number theory which uses analytic continuation.

Here is an example where Apostol uses analytic continuation ( In last line of proof) . 
 [image]

Equation (17) is $\zeta(s) = e^{G(s) } $

> What I can think about it --> In equation (17) both RHS and LHS are analytic if s is real and s>1 . But which result Apostol is using to extend its domain of analyticity. ( is he using the fact that both LHS and RHS are analytic for s>1 even when s belongs to Complex Numbers and hence extension of domain of analyticity is justify. 
>   I don't always get a complete understanding when analytic continuation is used .

Can someone please explain it if my argument is wrong.

Comment: @Eric Towers Sorry, (17) was cropped while posting image.

Comment: Given $F(s)=\sum_n f(n)n^{-s}$ with $f$ completely multiplicative and $F$ converging absolutely (thus analytic) for $\Re(s) > 1$ it is finding a Dirichlet series $G(s) = \sum_n f(n) \frac{\Lambda(n)}{\log n}n^{-s}$ again absolutely convergent thus analytic for $\Re(s) > 1$, such that $F(s) = e^{G(s)}$ for $s > A$ large enough, thus $F(s)-e^{G(s)}$ is analytic for $\Re(s) > 1$ and it vanishes on $(A,\infty)$ which implies it vanishes everywhere on $\Re(s) > 1$ (as non-constant analytic functions have isolated zeros). The concept of analytic continuation is not more complicated than that.

Comment: @reuns I know that $\zeta$(s) = $e^{G(s) } $  when s >1 and s belongs to real. Which result of complex analysis are you exactly using to prove that $\zeta$(s) = $e^{ G(s) } $ for all complex values s>1 ?Can you please mention the exact statement of that result!!

Comment: I said so, that $\zeta(s)-e^{G(s)}$ is analytic and that it has non-isolated zeros

Comment: @reuns  , but real line is not dense in complex plane. So, how $\zeta$(s) - $e^{G(s) } has non isolated zeroes?  I am sorry if my questions sound dumb to you but I ask them only because I cannot see how that true and I don't want to take them for granted without understanding reason behind them.

Comment: @reuns can you please elaborate your previous comment if you have some time to spare?

Comment: If $h(s)$ is non-constant analytic at $a$ and $h(a)=0$ then $h(s) = \sum_{n\ge N} (s-a)^n \frac{h^{(n)}(a)}{n!}\sim (s-a)^N \frac{h^{(N)}(a)}{N!}$ it doesn't vanish near $a$

Comment: @reuns by this result , as near a h is non - zero, so zeroes are isolated. But you are deducing the converse!!  ie h has isolated zeroes.

Comment: uh ???${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @reuns can you please explain in a bit detail? I am really sorry to disturb you and I know you have answered a lot of my questions but I am not getting this. Can you just tell what's wrong with my previous comment!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The heart of the matter is the following theorem.

**Identity Theorem.** Let $f$ be an analytic function in an open connected set $\Omega\subset\mathbb{C}$, and suppose that the zero set of $f$ has an accumulation point in $\Omega$. Then $f\equiv0$.

By applying this theorem to the difference between LHS and RHS of (17), we infer that the difference is identically zero in $\mathrm{Re}(\sigma)>0$.